# Program crashing, can't explain why?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int compare(char word[], char mystery[])
    {
        int i=0;int bool=1;
        while((i<=20)&&(bool==1))
        {
            if (word[i]==mystery[i])
                i++;
            else
                bool=0;
        }
        return bool;
    }
    char readCharacter()
    {
        char character = 0;

        character = getchar();
        character = toupper(character);
        while (getchar() != '\n') ;
        return character;
    }
    void readString(char *word,char *mystery)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter the word to guess : ");
    scanf("%s",word);
    while(*((word)+(i)) != '\0')
    {
        *((word)+(i))= toupper(*(word+i));
        *((mystery)+(i))='*';
        i++;
    }
    *(mystery+i)='\0';
}
void process(char *word,char *mystery,char letter,int *change)
{
    int i=0;
    while (*((word)+(i))!= '\0')
    {
        if (*((word)+(i))==letter)
        {
            *((mystery)+(i))=letter;
            *change=1;
        }
        i++;

    }

}
    void test(char *word,char *mystery, int triesleft)
    {
        if (*mystery!=*word)
            {
                printf("The mystery word is : %s",*mystery);
                printf("\n You have %d tries left.", triesleft);
            }
         else
         {
              printf("You won !");
         }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int triesleft = 10; int change=0;
        char word[20]; char mystery[20];char letter;
        readString(&word,&mystery);
        while((compare(word,mystery)==0) && (triesleft>0))
        {
            change=0;
            printf("Enter the letter :");
            letter=readCharacter();
            process(&word,&mystery,letter,&change);
            if ((change)==1)
                triesleft--;
            test(&word,&mystery,triesleft);
        }
        if (triesleft>0)
            return 0;
        printf("You lost.");
        return 1;

    }
```

I'm a beginner in C and I wanted to code a simple Hangman game in C and it compiled fine but it seems to crash after entering the first letter and I can't find a solution !
I don't know what may be the cause but I had a lot of trouble using strings in C, as they don't exist maybe it was a bad manipulation of that I don't know :/

Comment: Your program doesn't "compile fine", there's a ton of warnings raised. Make sure you turn on your compiler's warnings settings and fix them all. Also, start smaller. If you program crashes on the first function call, strip everything else out and simplify that function (make it do less stuff) until you understand what the problem is.

Comment: Please point the line where it is crashing and error messages shown

Comment: This line is a problem. `while((i<=20)&&(bool==1))`. For an array containing `20` items, the highest valid index is `19`, not `20`.

Comment: The first thing to do is as @Mat says, enable all the warnings, and fix the compilation problems. There are obviously several type mismatch problems.

Comment: Add printfs after very line and you will quickly find out where the problem is.  You need to learn to debug your program rather than depend on others to spot your errors.

Comment: Fixed the warnings along with other things from the comments and the programs doesn't crash anymore. The problem left is only in functionning now.

Comment: bool is a reserved word,  use a different word

Comment: getchar() returns an int, however, 'character' is defined as char, not int.

Comment: why return -1 when the user fails to guess the word?  the OS does not need to know that the user failed to quess the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first call to `readString` is enough to crash the program.

`word` and `mystery` are arrays, so `&word` is a `char **` not a `char *`. You should use

```
readString(word, mystery);
```

But compiler should have issue a warning on that. Warning are not there to distract beginners to to denote possible (probable if you do not understand the warning) mistakes.

There are probably other problems later ...

Comment: Fixed that and the warnings and the programs doesn't crash anymore. The problem left is only in functionning now.

Answer (score 0):

In the **readString()** function, you should use **'\0'** instead of **NULL**, as C strings are ended with this character.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't now if it was just 0 or NULL or something else :)

Comment: Glad I was helpful. And please do upvote whenever you find an answer useful.

Comment: I tried to, it says I don't have enough reputation to do so ><

Comment: actually you want to 'accept' the answer, there is no need to try to perform an up-vote

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a variable named bool as it is a type. In C, it is not actually defined for all compilers as bool is not part of the standard but some compilers and some platform will define it anyway

Comment: Only if you include `stdbool.h`, and that would be a hard compile error.

Comment: There is also a chance that this is not actual C but compiled as C++

Comment: The code would not compile as C++. OP says it compiles.

Comment: The code is C and it compiles, didn't include stdbool.h but CodeBlocks was still 'coloring' it so i changed it to boole. Thank you